# C++ - Unable to call inline std::cerr inside of a ternary operator

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I'm trying to make a very simple setter method that checks if the `start` value isn't higher than the `end` value before setting it.

This is the basic code:

```cpp
if (start <= this->end) {
    this->start = start;
} else {
    cerr << "Start cannot be higher than end." << endl;
}
```

I tried simplifying the method by using an inline if statement like so:

```cpp
(start <= this->end) ? (this->start = start) : (cerr << "Start cannot be higher than end." << endl);
```

But IntelliSense tells me the following issue: `function "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> &) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`

Uhh, I'm a bit confused as to what "deleted function" has to do with turning a simple if statement into an inline one. Could use some help. Thanks!

Comment: This is the **ternary operator**. It is not a replacement for `if ... else ...`. Keep the original version.

Comment: @PeteBecker Is there a replacement similar to an "inline if statement"?

Comment: You can put your `if ... else ...` all on one line if you want to. <g> there are various tricks you can use to make the ternary operator work, but that’s like putting in a screw with a hammer. Better to use the right tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ternary conditional expression `a ? b : c` is an *expression* and is therefore not equivalent to `if (a) { b } else { c }`.

Because it's an expression, it must have a type (and, if that type is not `void`, it has a value too). This is why you can put a ternary conditional on the right-hand side of an assignment (or even the left-hand side in some cases).

The type of a conditional expression is determined from the types of its second and third operands. If they have the same type, then the result is that type. If there is not some "unambiguous" type that both operand types can be converted to, then the ternary expression does not default to a `void` results; it instead results in a compilation error.

In your case, the two operands are:

- `(this->start = start)`
- `(cerr << "Start cannot be higher than end." << endl)`

The former has, I assume, some numeric type (the type of `this->start`) while the latter has `std::ostream&` type. There is no canonical "common type" of these two types, or in other words, the ternary operator has no "obvious" result type and a compilation error occurs.

An `if` statement would solve this problem. If you insist on using a conditional operator, you can do so like this:

```
(start <= this->end)
? void(this->start = start)
: void(cerr << "Start cannot be higher than end." << endl);
```

Here, both the second and third expressions are cast to `void` and the entire ternary expression therefore has result type `void`.

Note that you can't have something like `break` or `return` as one of the operands. `condition ? void(return foo) : void(return bar)` will not work, because `return <expr>` is a *statement*, not an expression. It has no type, not even `void`. In this case, you can only use an `if` statement. However, you can `throw` inside a conditional expression since `throw <expr>` is an expression.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the statement for true case and false case must be matched.

Try this with `, this->start` (comma operator, then `this->start`) is added to the false case to match type:

```
(start <= this->end) ? (this->start = start) : (cerr << "Start cannot be higher than end." << endl, this->start);
```

By the way, my suggestion is you should simply write `if` statement in one line instead of using conditional operator like this if you want things in one line:

```
if (start <= this->end) this->start = start; else cerr << "Start cannot be higher than end." << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use the 2nd solution. Question, why does it require a `, something`? I usually do stuff like `a > b ? a = b : NULL;` but your 2nd solution makes a whole lot more sense to use in these situations. Although I still don't get why I need to do that.

Comment: @yeho both operands of the `?:` operator must evaluate to the same type. `cerr >> ...` by itself returns an `ostream&` reference to `cerr`, which is a different type than `this->start`, hence why `, this->start` is needed after `cerr >> ...` (the `,` comma operator evaluates both operands, but returns the 2nd operand).  `a > b ? a = b : NULL;` works as-is if `a` is a numeric type, since `NULL` is just an alias for `0`.